# JS dropdown doesnt react on change

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I am trying to make calculator by calculating the values but when you change drop down option, result doesn't made changes, any solution , thanks

```html
</head>
<body>

  <script>
function add() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  document.getElementById("c").value = ((x * y)*1.1).toFixed(2);
 
}
</script>
  
Enter 1st Number :
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="add()">
<br>
<br>Enter 2nd Number :
<select type="text" id="b" onchange="add()">
  <option value="1">6 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="2">12 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="3">18 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="4">24 mjeseci</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Result :
<input type="text" id="c" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910659/js-dropdown-doesnt-react-on-change/41911119#41911119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just **change your function name** and then use `onchange`.
According to W3Schools :

> onchange Execute a JavaScript when a user changes the selected option of a  element

Here is the Correct Code:

```html
  <script>
function addnum() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  document.getElementById("c").value = ((x * y)*1.1).toFixed(2);
 
}
</script>
  
Enter 1st Number :
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="addnum()">
<br>
<br>Enter 2nd Number :
<select type="text" id="b" onchange="addnum()">
  <option value="1">6 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="2">12 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="3">18 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="4">24 mjeseci</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Result :
<input type="text" id="c" >
```

Comment: Thank You all, one more question , if somebody enter "," (comma) for decimal point for first number then result is wrong -any solution for this ?

Comment: @Dalibormaric use parseFloat.

Comment: Float also doesnt reacts when insert comma instead point for first number

Comment: Thanx Mohammad I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the dropdown so it also fires the add() function.

Make sure your script is run at the bottom of the page, after all the DOM elements are loaded.

```
<body>
    <!-- Your existing HTML -->
    Enter 1st Number :
    <input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="add()">
    <br>
    <br>Enter 2nd Number :
    <select type="text" id="b" >
        <option value="1">6 mjeseci</option>
        <option value="2">12 mjeseci</option>
        <option value="3">18 mjeseci</option>
        <option value="4">24 mjeseci</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>Result :
    <input type="text" id="c" >

    <!-- Put your script after the HTML -->
    <script>
        function add() {
          var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
          var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
          document.getElementById("c").value = ((x * y)*1.1).toFixed(2);
        }

        // Event listener on dropdown will call the function add()
        document.getElementById("b").addEventListener('change', add, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Really the reason for not working of the code is function name `add` because add is a already defined function in HTMLSelectElement 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add

add() function is used to add option to the select Element.

```js
function addition() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  document.getElementById("c").value = ((x * y) * 1.1).toFixed(2);

}

var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
opt1.value = "1";
opt1.text = "Option: Value 1";
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>


  Enter 1st Number :
  <input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="addition()">
  <br>
  <br>Enter 2nd Number :
  <select type="text" id="b" onchange="addition()">
    <option value="1">6 mjeseci</option>
    <option value="2">12 mjeseci</option>
    <option value="3">18 mjeseci</option>
    <option value="4">24 mjeseci</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Result :
  <input type="text" id="c">
</body>

<br>
<br>
<br>This is the demo for add() function:
<select type="text" id="Addfun" onchange="add(opt1)">
  <option value="1">6 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="2">12 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="3">18 mjeseci</option>
  <option value="4">24 mjeseci</option>
</select>
<br>After changing the option see the options in dropdown.

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately function name 'add' is conflicting with some built in logic.
So, just change function name

```
Enter 1st Number:<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="calc()" /><br>
<br>Enter 2nd Number :
<select id="b" onchange="calc()">
  <option value="1">x1</option>
  <option value="2">x2</option>
  <option value="3">x3</option>
  <option value="4">x4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Result :<input type="text" id="c" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
      var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
      var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
      document.getElementById("c").value = (x * y);
}
</script>
```